# JavaScript array length seems to be 0 even after data gets populated into it from fetch

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, promise, fetch

I am using the Google Custom Search JSON API in my app. I have a simple Scraper class that I use to scrap data from Google Search using the API, here is its code:

```
class Scraper {
  constructor(apiKey, cx) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.cx = cx;
  }
  scrap(search, platformUrl = "google.com") {
    this.search = search;
    this.platformUrl = platformUrl;

    if (platformUrl === "google.com") {
      const results = [];

      fetch(
        `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.items.forEach((item) => {
            let title = item.title;
            let link = item.link;
            results.push([title, link]);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          fetch(
            `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=11`
          )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              data.items.forEach((item) => {
                let title = item.title;
                let link = item.link;
                results.push([title, link]);
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              fetch(
                `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=21`
              )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  data.items.forEach((item) => {
                    let title = item.title;
                    let link = item.link;
                    results.push([title, link]);
                  });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (results) {
          resolve(results);
        } else {
          reject("No results");
        }
      });

      return promise;
    } else {
      const results = [];

      fetch(
        `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.items.forEach((item) => {
            let title = item.title;
            let link = item.link;
            results.push([title, link]);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          fetch(
            `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=11&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
          )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              data.items.forEach((item) => {
                let title = item.title;
                let link = item.link;
                results.push([title, link]);
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              fetch(
                `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=21&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
              )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  data.items.forEach((item) => {
                    let title = item.title;
                    let link = item.link;
                    results.push([title, link]);
                  });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      let promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        if (results) {
          resolve(results);
        } else {
          reject("No results");
        }
      });

      return promise;
    }
  }
}
```

And it is successful in fetching the data, and when I `console.log()` the data out, it works as well. However, the problem arises when I use the `.length` property to get the length of the array, it says it's 0, even when there are about 30 items in the array.

```
const scraper = new Scraper(api_key, cx);
const data = scraper.scrap("My Google Search", "google.com").then((data) => {
  console.log(data);  // This returns an array with 30 items in it.
  console.log(data.length);  // While this returns 0.
});
```

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong? Ideally, it should say that the `length` is 30 since the number of items in the array is 30. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Update, here is a sample output from the results of `console.log(data);`:

```
[
  [
    "Mohammed Sannan V S - Associate Product Manager ...",
    "https://in.linkedin.com/in/mohammedsannan",
  ],
  [
    "Mohammed Sannan V S (@sannan_v) / Twitter",
    "https://twitter.com/sannan_v",
  ],
  ["Company – ZENAQ | Official-Web", "https://zenaq.com/en/company/"],
  [
    "Sannan butt - QA Lead - Pixako Technologies (Pvt.) Ltd | LinkedIn",
    "https://pk.linkedin.com/in/sannanbutt-03216205384",
  ],
  [
    "Nishant Sannan - Sr Advanced Manufacturing Engineer - Honeywell ...",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/in/nishantsannan1",
  ],
  ["Sant Ambroeus", "https://www.santambroeus.com/"],
  [
    "What Happens When Software Testers Become Friends With ...",
    "https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/what-happens-when-software-testers-become-friends-development-butt",
  ],
  [
    "The Information Architecture Framework is Essential for Product ...",
    "https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/the-information-architecture-framework-is-essential-for-product-design-b2a5a7c8f393",
  ],
  [
    "Group Companies (Domestic)｜Group Structure｜Sanwa Holdings ...",
    "https://www.sanwa-hldgs.co.jp/english/group/domestic.html",
  ],
  [
    "Visual Design Vs Functional Design | by Sannan Malik | Bootcamp",
    "https://bootcamp.uxdesign.cc/visual-design-vs-functional-design-c92752fc48ff",
  ],
  [
    "LED Chip - Products - San'an Optoelectronics Co., Ltd.",
    "https://www.sanan-e.com/en/led-chip.html",
  ],
  [
    "Sannan Ijaz - Canada | Professional Profile | LinkedIn",
    "https://au.linkedin.com/in/sannanijaz",
  ],
  [
    "What is the role of a Senior Product Designer? | by Sannan Malik ...",
    "https://medium.com/@sannanmalikofficial/what-is-the-role-of-a-senior-product-designer-e42d9323e455",
  ],
  [
    'Hiroyuki "Sannan" Ikeda MMA Stats, Pictures, News, Videos ...',
    "https://www.sherdog.com/fighter/Hiroyuki-Ikeda-16441",
  ],
  [
    "Products | Bridgelux, Inc. LED Lighting",
    "https://www.bridgelux.com/products",
  ],
  [
    "Flotation Behavior of Complex Sulfide Ores in the Presence of ...",
    "https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijps/2017/4835842/",
  ],
  [
    "Sannan on Spotify",
    "https://open.spotify.com/artist/2wLEJb2x4zKRvaisdFKZQH",
  ],
  [
    "Studies on chitin, 4. Evidence for formation of block and random ...",
    "https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/macp.1977.021781203",
  ],
  [
    "Sannan Skarn | shahjee",
    "https://www.shahjeeitl.com/product-page/sannan-skarn-1",
  ],
  [
    "Stream Sannan music | Listen to songs, albums, playlists for free on ...",
    "https://soundcloud.com/sannan",
  ],
  [
    "Guntur Sannam Chillies – Diaspora Co.",
    "https://www.diasporaco.com/products/sannam-chillies",
  ],
  [
    "Sannan Industries - Manufacturer from Focal Point, Jalandhar, India ...",
    "https://www.indiamart.com/sannan-industries/aboutus.html",
  ],
  ["Senn Retractors", "https://www.alimed.com/senn-retractors.html"],
  ["Power-Sanan IC", "https://www.sanan-ic.com/en/power-electronics"],
  [
    "St Sannans Church Bedwellty 2 Photograph by Steve Purnell - Pixels",
    "https://pixels.com/featured/1-st-sannans-church-bedwellty-2-steve-purnell.html",
  ],
  [
    "St Sannan's Church in Caerphilly, Caerphilly - Find a Grave Cemetery",
    "https://www.findagrave.com/cemetery/2470473/st-sannan's-church",
  ],
  [
    "Sannan Zafar - Senior Dimensional Engineer - Tesla | LinkedIn",
    "https://ca.linkedin.com/in/sannan",
  ],
  [
    "Studies on Chitin XII. Chitin Derivatives Having 1,4 ...",
    "https://www.nature.com/articles/pj198692.pdf",
  ],
  [
    "Highway Safety Solutions - Roadway Safety Products - Coral Sales ...",
    "http://www.coralsales.com/about/scholarshipprogram/pastrecipients/",
  ],
  [
    "IBM SANnav Management Portal and SANnav Global View deliver ...",
    "https://www.ibm.com/common/ssi/ShowDoc.wss?docURL=/common/ssi/rep_ca/1/897/ENUS120-061/index.html&request_locale=en",
  ],
]
```

Updated code suggested by @Keith:

```
class Scraper {
  constructor(apiKey, cx) {
    this.apiKey = apiKey;
    this.cx = cx;
  }
  scrap(search, platformUrl = "google.com") {
    this.search = search;
    this.platformUrl = platformUrl;

    if (platformUrl === "google.com") {
      const results = [];

      const requestResults = fetch(
        `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.items.forEach((item) => {
            let title = item.title;
            let link = item.link;
            results.push([title, link]);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          fetch(
            `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=11`
          )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              data.items.forEach((item) => {
                let title = item.title;
                let link = item.link;
                results.push([title, link]);
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              fetch(
                `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=21`
              )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  data.items.forEach((item) => {
                    let title = item.title;
                    let link = item.link;
                    results.push([title, link]);
                    return results;
                  });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      return requestResults;
    } else {
      const results = [];

      const requestResults = fetch(
        `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
      )
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
          data.items.forEach((item) => {
            let title = item.title;
            let link = item.link;
            results.push([title, link]);
          });
        })
        .then(() => {
          fetch(
            `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=11&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
          )
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              data.items.forEach((item) => {
                let title = item.title;
                let link = item.link;
                results.push([title, link]);
              });
            })
            .then(() => {
              fetch(
                `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${api_key}&cx=${cx}&start=21&siteSearch=${platformUrl}`
              )
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((data) => {
                  data.items.forEach((item) => {
                    let title = item.title;
                    let link = item.link;
                    results.push([title, link]);
                    return results;
                  });
                });
            });
        })
        .catch((err) => console.error(err));

      return requestResults;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252200/discussion-on-question-by-xybox-javascript-array-length-seems-to-be-0-even-after); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is accessing `results` synchronously, before any of the `then` callbacks has executed.

Be aware that the code is not executed in the order that it appears in your code: the `then` callbacks are executed asynchronously, i.e. after the method `scrap` has already returned.

It doesn't help to create yet another promise with `new Promise` -- this is an antipattern. You should return a promise that corresponds to the last `fetch` related promise.

Another unfortunate aspect of your code is that it indents deeper and deeper. This is what is known as the "callback hell", and one of the reasons why promises are handy, is that they can be used to *avoid* a callback hell. Yet, your code does not take that benefit.

Moreover, there is needless code repetition. All those URLs are similar and so is the processing of the responses.

Finally, `async` and `await` can help to make the code more elegant.

Here is how you could do it:

```
class Scraper {
    constructor(apiKey, cx) {
        this.apiKey = apiKey;
        this.cx = cx;
    }
    async scrap(search, platformUrl="google.com") {
        const getJson = (url, start=1) => fetch(`${url}&start=${start}`).then(response => response.json());

        const url = `https://customsearch.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?q=${search}&key=${this.apiKey}&cx=${this.cx}`
                  + (platformUrl === "google.com" ? "" : "&siteSearch=${platformUrl}");
        const results = [];
        for (let page = 1; page <= 3; page++) {
            results.push(...(await getJson(url, page*10-9)).items.map(({title, link}) => [title, link]));
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks a lot for the answer, and thank you so much for the explanation as well, this really clears promises for me. Have an excellent day.

Comment: Wow, you were fast to check the answer and come back to me. That is really refreshing ;-)

Comment: You don't know how desperate I was for this, you not only solved my problem but also made this confusing concept clear to me, I had totally misunderstood promises before this. Thanks once again.

Comment: @XYBOX  As pointed out in the comments, `&key=${api_key}`,  that `api_key` will be referencing some global,  you maybe meant to do `this.api_key`, otherwise what was the point of assigning it during constructor?.  The same would apply to `cx`..  `this.cx` is not the same as `cx`..

Comment: @Keith I see, I missed that accidentally I suppose.